# How to partition a stream fractionally in python?

Tags: python, stream, buffer, chunking

I'm processing a stream of data (in chunks i.e. buffered) and would like to send an arbitrary fraction of it to one stream, and the rest to a second stream.

For example, let's say the length of the total list is 20. If 15% of the list needs to go into the first output list, then in the end there should be 3 items in the first list and 17 in the other. If I'm processing the list in chunks of size 5, then I'd like to send roughly one item a chunk to the first stream, but zero items once. Over the 4 chunks, I'd send 1+1+1+0 = 3 items to the first list.

If the list was sufficiently large it seems like it would be appropriate to rely on the law of large numbers and randomly select where to send every item. Given that it won't always be, all that I can think of is to maintain two counters and decide where to send every item based on how it would affect the current ratio ("controlling" to the desired ratio). Is this the best way?

With my current approach I'll be writing somewhat custom logic when it seems like either `partition` or `grouper` from [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) would be more generic starting points for what I need.

Comment: Why can't you send the first 3 items of the first chunk to stream 1, then everything else to stream 2?

Comment: That assumes you know the total number of items in the stream. Is that the case?

Comment: Right, you don't know the total number of items in the stream.

Comment: Then I think your idea of the two counters may be the simplest solution.

Comment: How close do you have to get to the desired percentage? If there are only 10 items, how are you going to put 1.5 items in stream 1?

Comment: As close as possible. Right, I'm realizing the problem statement may be incomplete. It seems we need a loss function to define how to "control" to a ratio. For example, someone may need to minimize the absolute difference between the desired fraction and the current fraction. Someone else may be happy to add to the first stream if the desired fraction is below the current fraction, and add to the second otherwise.